# Solution to highlighting files with errors in TypeScript in Vim in a file tree

Tags: typescript, vim, error-handling

Does anyone know of a good plugin that I could use?
Right now VSCode highlights files with errors so we can quickly zoom in and correct them. I don't know of any Vim solution for it so far.

Answer (score 2):

Vim doesn’t have much in the way of a filetree model.

For this instance, you’ll be better off using the quickfix list and leveraging vim’s pre-existing machinery around it to quickly navigate errors. See, e.g., `:help quickfix`.

There are many ways to set it, including using `:make`, the `-q` flag, or a plugin like ALE.

Then use `:cnext` and `:cprev` to navigate between errors (bound to `]q` and `[q` in tpope/unimpaired plugin).